# Ngrx state observable first subscription is always undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5, ngrx

Ive recently start using late ngrx (4) and angular 4 versions.
I recently noticed a weird case that always happens.
No matter where in my code., when ever I do something like:

```
const subscription = 
this.store.select(*someselector*).subscribe(() =>{
console.log(subscription) ;
}
```

In previous ngrx version (not 4) and also older type script version (was 2.0.10) the subscription variable would just be undefined in the first time (which is my first question)

Now that I have upgraded to ngrx 4 and typescript 2.4.1, if I try to do a check like (inside the subscribe callback) 
    if (subscription) subscription.unsubscribe();
Im getting a reference error telling me subscription is undefined.

I don't understand both why in the first time its undefined nor why after I upgraded I can't check if its defined with the if statement without getting an exception.

Comment: can you post your reducer code ?